# Vagrant allows to SSH onto it only the first time

Tags: ssh, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm trying to configure my first Vagrant box.
However it allows me to ssh onto it (with `vagrant ssh`) only the first time after `vagrant up`
But when I log out of the VM I can't log back onto it.

Doing Vagrant provision yields:

```
▶ vagrant provision
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
SSH authentication failed! This is typically caused by the public/private
keypair for the SSH user not being properly set on the guest VM. Please
verify that the guest VM is setup with the proper public key, and that
the private key path for Vagrant is setup properly as well.
```

And trying to ssh into it yields:

```
▶ vagrant ssh       
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Even if I give it the default password (`vagrant`) it rejects it and asks for it again 3 times.

When I start it in GUI mode, after writing any credentials whole console clears out and asks to log in again.

Tried destroying and rebuilding the VM, clearing `project/.vagrant` and `~/.vagrant.d`.
Always the same result.

Adding `config.ssh.insert_key = false` to Vagrantfile changed nothing.

My box is `ubuntu/trusty64` and my ssh-config looks like that:

```
▶ vagrant ssh-config
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/iraasta/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

Trying to ssh manually with `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222` and password `vagrant` also returns Permission Denied

Comment: I experience the same issue, even gui login stopped functioning after the first successful run and shutdown via ssh. VB v.5.0.16